# how to shutdown a VM on hyper V at a certain time?

Tags: hyper-v, shutdown

I wasn't able to find anything online, with physical servers I could run something like `shutdown /s /f /t 1000` or use task scheduler. What I'm looking to do is shut down a VM but want to shut down the VMs just before the physical is shut down (site will have the power turned off)

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What prevents you from doing this in your VM?

Comment: There isn't one @Lenniey but it isn't very clean - is there no way to do this via HyperV/the host or do we simply need to run the command via the VM itself?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/stop-vm?view=win10-ps

Comment: Thanks for that, there doesn't appear to be a time-related parameter, however, it could easily be run via scheduler instead.

Comment: It isn't very clean? Using the shutdown command is no different in a VM then it is in a physical machine.

Comment: @joeqwerty It's not clean in the sense I would need to remote to every single VM and run the command when at times I'll be running hosts with 20+ VMs on them and other times need to do this with multiple hosts.

Comment: OK, so it isn't efficient... but it works exactly the same way. I just wanted to make sure I was understanding you.

Comment: Hm well, you'll always need some loop (or a list, or wildcard, etc.), either over your VMs or your physical servers. PowerShell is much prettier for this, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use task scheduler for a specific point in time, or, for your example, use `Start-Sleep` combined with `Stop-VM` (or `Suspend-VM`), e.g.:

`Start-Sleep -s 1000; Stop-VM -Name TestVM [-Force]` on your Hyper-V host.